# How to resynchronize with MKS via command line with Version 7.6.1.260?

Tags: command-line, versioning, mks

I am really struggling with synchronizing my MKS project via command line/ batch file.
Currently we are using this really old version 7.6.1.260 of MKS.
So far I cannot find the si interface.

So I am trying to use the pj command. However I cannot find any good documentation about it and
the "MKS man" says "There is no entry for pj". So I really really need your help.

So basically what I want to do is something like `pj -P sandbox.pj` and my whole project is synchronized. Optionally it would be nice to just overwrite everything if any problems occur.

I really hope there is someone that can help me.

Best regards!!

Answer (score 0):

...at least what I found out so far is that is possible with pj -Psandbox.pj refresh. Even though this is not recursive, but the rest can be done with some scripting.